# Invert a list from a file

Tags: python

I need to read dictionary items from a file and write the inverted dictionary to a file, but I don't know why this code is not working.

```
file = open("copy.txt", "w") 
file.write("'europe' : ['Romania', 'Italy', 'Greece', 'Netherlands', 'Austria', 'Vatican', 'Germany', 'Hungary', 'Bulgaria', 'CzechRepublic', 'Belgium', 'Scotland', 'Spain', 'Portugal', 'UnitedKingdom', 'Sweden', 'Ireland', 'Norway', 'Slovakia', 'Poland','France']") 
file.close()

fin = open('copy.txt')
for line in fin:
    word = line.strip()
    print(word)

def invert_dic(d):
    inverse = dict()
    for key in d:
        val = d[key]
        for x in val:
          inverse[x] = [key]
    return inverse

print(invert_dic(word))
```

Comment: It doesn't work because `word` is a string, not a dict.

Answer (score 1):

You should use json for writing/reading dicts to/from files.

```
import json

continent_dict = {'europe' : ['Romania', 'Italy', 'Greece', 'Netherlands', 'Austria', 'Vatican', 'Germany', 'Hungary', 'Bulgaria', 'CzechRepublic', 'Belgium', 'Scotland', 'Spain', 'Portugal', 'UnitedKingdom', 'Sweden', 'Ireland', 'Norway', 'Slovakia', 'Poland','France']}

# dump continent dictionary to json file
with open('copy.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(continent_dict, file)

# load continent dictionary from json file
with open('copy.json', 'r') as file:
    loaded_dict = json.load(file)
```

Now you will be able to call invert_dic on loaded_dict without an issue.